# How to replace multiple strings in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to replace multiple strings in a list but I'm falling short. The string i want to replace is. The numbers represent the **correct** order of the words

```
sentence = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

I want to replace the numbers with text 'i', 'put', 'this', 'here' so that it looks like below

```
['i', 'put', 'this', 'here']
```

I found a line of code that manages to replace only one word.

```
newsentence = [n.replace('1', 'I') for n in sentence]
```

I attempted to repeat the code 4 times so that it would replace all of the numbers.

```
newsentence = [n.replace('1', 'I') for n in sentence]
newsentence = [n.replace('2', 'put') for n in sentence]
newsentence = [n.replace('3', 'this') for n in sentence]
newsentence = [n.replace('4', 'here') for n in sentence]
```

but the result is that the last replacement is executed resulting in

```
['1', '2', '3', 'here']
```

Thanks for any feedback

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? In particular, what are your inputs and desired  output? As far as I can see, your inputs are `['1', '2', '3', '4']` / `['i', 'put', 'this', 'here']`. Your desired output is `['i', 'put', 'this', 'here']`. So there is no problem here?

Comment: I wanted to put those values into the list newsentence. The list ['i', 'put', 'this', 'here'] does not exist yet. Only the numbers list exists. After i replace the numbers with the string then it will exist. Keyur Potdar answered is perfect. If you didn't understand what i was trying to do, you could check out his answer

Comment: So how do you get your strings 'i', 'put', 'this', 'there'. If they aren't in a list, where are they stored? Almost certainly, this kind of sequential `replace` is *not* the road you want to go down. Check out @KeyurPotdar's edit with a `dict` solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you know which words you need to replace. Using the following approach will do just that in `O(n)` time.

```
changes = {
    '1': 'i',
    '2': 'put',
    '3': 'this',
    '4': 'here'
}

sentence = ['1', '2', '3', '4']

newsentence = []
for word in sentence:
    try:
        newsentence.append(changes[word])
    except KeyError:
        newsentence.append(word)

print(newsentence)
# ['i', 'put', 'this', 'here']
```

**Explanation:**

What you've to do here is check if the list item is available in the dictionary. If it is available, use it's value and append that value in the new list. Otherwise, append the value of the old list directly.

The code `changes[word]` in the line `newsentence.append(changes[word])` will raise a `KeyError` if the key is not available in the dictionary. That's why we are catching that error and appending the word directly.

Also, note that this code uses the [EAFP principle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360858/what-is-the-eafp-principle-in-python).

---

**Note:** The following code is to only show you where you were going wrong. Avoid using it (reason mentioned below).

To help you understand what's happening in your code, have a look at the following snippet:

```
>>> sentence = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> newsentence = [n.replace('1', 'I') for n in sentence]
>>> newsentence
['I', '2', '3', '4']
>>> newsentence = [n.replace('2', 'put') for n in sentence]
>>> newsentence
['1', 'put', '3', '4']
>>> newsentence = [n.replace('3', 'this') for n in sentence]
>>> newsentence
['1', '2', 'this', '4']
...
```

In short, you're replacing a single item from the original sentence, i.e. `['1', '2', '3', '4']` each time. To replace all the items replace `sentence` with `newsentence` after the first replace line.

```
sentence = ['1', '2', '3', '4']

newsentence = [n.replace('1', 'I') for n in sentence]
newsentence = [n.replace('2', 'put') for n in newsentence]
newsentence = [n.replace('3', 'this') for n in newsentence]
newsentence = [n.replace('4', 'here') for n in newsentence]

print(newsentence)
# ['I', 'put', 'this', 'here']
```

But, **avoid** this code, as the cost is quadratic; or to be more precise, it's `O(m*n)` where `m` is the size of the list and `n` is the number of words which you want to replace; and obviously it's not feasible to write this if the list is even larger.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar, +2 for the dictionary solution. -1 for the start bit on sequential `replace`. Net +1 :). Seems like a classic XY problem.

Comment: @jpp, yes, even I didn't like the replace solution, but I posted that to answer the OP's question as it is. I know it looks like an XY problem. So, in such cases, should I post the first solution and the second, or directly go for the second?

Comment: @KeyurPotdar, it's a good question. My personal preference is just show the *right* way to encourage good practice. I'd hate for the user to see your solution and just stick with sequential `replace`.

Comment: Out of curiosity how does the key value work with the code newsentence.append(changes[word])

Comment: A list comprehension equivalent of your solution: `newsentence = [changes.get(word, word) for word in sentence]`. The second argument to `dict.get` is the fallback value if the key is missing.

Comment: @SethMMorton, I was not aware of the get method with its fallback value. Thanks for sharing. And I think you should post it as an answer.

Comment: I think Potdar answer was carefully crafted, but Seth's is really pythonic. We can't upvote last the same way as a comment, should be an answer I say too.

Comment: @KeyurPotdar Thanks for the suggestion. I also added my thoughts on why one should use a `dict` beyond simple performance concerns.

Answer (score 5):

Please see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49465475/1399279) of @KeyurPotdar for an explanation for why your original solution did not work.

For a list-comprehension-based solution to your issue (which it seems like you were after), you can create a mapping of inputs to outputs, and then iterate over the mapping with your inputs

```
mapping = {
    '1': 'i',
    '2': 'put',
    '3': 'this',
    '4': 'here',
}
sentence = ['1', '2', '3', '4']
newsentence = [mapping[word] for word in sentence]
# ['I', 'put', 'this', 'here']
```

This is nice, but if you decide to throw more inputs at `mapping` for which you have not defined an output you would get a `KeyError`. To easily handle this you can use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get), which allows you to provide a fallback value to be returned if the given key is missing.

```
newsentence = [mapping.get(word, word) for word in sentence]
# ['I', 'put', 'this', 'here']
```

[A good reference on `dict.get`.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11041405/1399279)

---

Not only is a mapping-based solution more efficient in this case (see @KeyurPotdar's notes on that), but separating your code into data and logic is The Right Thing To Do™.

If you can transform a problem from being code/logic based (such as the sequence of list comprehensions in the original question) to be mapping-based you will almost always win on maintainability and code clarity.  Observe that this solution both data and logic are mixed:

```
newsentence = [n.replace('1', 'I') for n in sentence]
newsentence = [n.replace('2', 'put') for n in newsentence]
newsentence = [n.replace('3', 'this') for n in newsentence]
newsentence = [n.replace('4', 'here') for n in newsentence]
```

However, in a mapping based solution they are separated

```
# DATA
mapping = {
    '1': 'i',
    '2': 'put',
    '3': 'this',
    '4': 'here',
}

# LOGIC
newsentence = [mapping.get(word, word) for word in sentence]
```

What does this buy you? Suppose down the road you end up having to support mapping 1000 words, and these words change often. Having the words mixed with the logic makes them more challenging to find, and makes it harder to mentally decouple if a change will just affect the data or may also accidentally change control flow. With a mapping-based solution one is positive that a change only affects the data.

Consider that we needed to add a mapping of `'1a'` to `'we'`.  In the mixed logic/data example it would be very easy to miss changing `sentence` to `newsentence`:

```
newsentence = [n.replace('1', 'I') for n in sentence]
newsentence = [n.replace('1a', 'we') for n in sentence]
newsentence = [n.replace('2', 'put') for n in newsentence]
newsentence = [n.replace('3', 'this') for n in newsentence]
newsentence = [n.replace('4', 'here') for n in newsentence]
```

Oops! In the mapping-based example this type of error is not possible by design.

Further, by decoupling data from logic one can start storing the data in separate files (such as JSON or YAML). This makes version control a bit more straightforward. It then opens up the possibility to have user-customizable mappings that you do not have to hard-code into your script. Decoupling == good.

Comment: Great explanation! Much needed for all the people who just started using Python (or simply programming in general).

Comment: I agree (and also with the comment above). In particular the last paragraph is good to show beginner's how data in code can be transformed in configuration files for easy extension without touching the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
newsentence = [n.replace('1', 'I') for n in sentence]
newsentence = [n.replace('2', 'put') for n in newsentence]
newsentence = [n.replace('3', 'this') for n in newsentence]
newsentence = [n.replace('4', 'here') for n in newsentence]
```

This means that each time, it changes the previous one, rather than reverting to the original, then just doing one replace.
You can also use `format()`:

```
sentence='{1}{2}{3}{4}{5}'
sentence.format('I', 'put', 'this', 'here')
```

See [this page](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-string-formatters-in-python-3) for more on the `format()` function.

Answer (score 0):

There's a translate method by which you can make multiple replace possible

```
s = '1 2 3 4'
replaced_string = s.translate(str.maketrans({'1': 'I', '2': 'put', '3': 'this', '4': 'here'}))
print(replaced_string)

#output: I put this here
```

You can avoid nested replace statements this way
Cheers!